# how to check logs of deleted params in parameter store of Systems Manager in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-systems-manager

some how params are deleted from parameter store of Systems Manager in ec2 console.
am unable to find out who deleted those, can anyone please let me know how to do that ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use cloud trail events, up to 90 days, to check the events - filter events based on **Event Name** as **DeleteParameter**.